# Is improper integral $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\ln(\sin x)}$ convergent or divergent

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

can someone help me with this integral

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{\ln(\sin x)}dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\ln(\sin x)}dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \frac{1}{\ln(\sin x)}dx$$
And because of symmetry i evaluate one of those integral, and i have taylor expand sinx at $\pi/2$
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \frac{1}{\ln(\sin x)}dx$$
$$\ln(\sin x)=\ln \left ( 1-\frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^2+O(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^4\right )$$
I'm stuck
how should i proceed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust As $x\to 0^+$ doesn't $\frac 1{\log(\sin x)} \to 0$?

Comment: @user: oooops, yes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I had the same bad idea at a first sight but then I realized that it was completely wrong! The argument works at $x=\frac \pi 2$ of course.

Comment: Your Taylor expansion is correct, and you can continue with $\log(1+\epsilon)$ to get $\log(\sin x)=-\frac12(x-\pi/2)^2+O((x-\pi/2)^4)$, to conclude that the integral is divergent.

Comment: $\displaystyle{1 \over \ln\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)} \sim -\,{2 \over \left(\,{x - \pi/2}\,\right)^{2}}$ as $\displaystyle x \to \pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{-\ln(\sin x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{2}{-\ln(\sin x)}dx\overset{t=\sin x}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2}{-\ln t\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\\
> \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2}{-\ln t}dt\overset{y=-\ln t}=\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{2e^{-y}}{y}dy>\int^{1}_{0} \frac{2e^{-y}}{y}dy> \frac2e\int^{1}_{0} \frac{1}{y}dy
$$
which is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to consider that eventually as $x \to {\frac \pi 2}^-$

$$-\ln(1-(1-\sin (x)))\le 1-\sin x =1-\cos\left(\frac \pi 2-x\right)\le \frac \pi 2 -x$$

therefore

$$-\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{1}{\ln(\sin x)}dx\ge \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{1}{\frac \pi 2 -x}dx=\int_0^\frac \pi 2 \frac 1y\,dy=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\ln(\sin x)}+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\ln(\sin x)}=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\ln(\sin x)}$$
now with $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ we get:
$$I=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\ln(\cos x)}$$
and so:
$$2I=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{\ln(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{\ln(\cos x)}\right)dx$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(\sin(x)\cos(x))}{\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)}dx$$
This just gives you another way of writing it but I think it shows more clearly what happens for $x\to\pi/2$